# String concatenation in C

Tags: c, string, concatenation

```
char *str1 = malloc(256*sizeof(char));
char *str2 = "stack"
for (i=0;i<15;i++){
     sprintf(str1,"%s%s",str1,str2);
} 
printf("%s\n",str1);
```

I'm trying to concat str2 to str1 at each loop count. But this code segment works but vulnerable. 
Whats the best way to concat them?

Comment: This code doesn't initialize the data pointed to by `str1`.

Comment: For this to work at all you should make sure that str1[0] is a null byte. Not guaranteed by malloc. And this is a really terrible insecure way, use strncat. or snprintf (but beware the null byte warning).

Comment: char *str2="stack"; missing semicolon wowo you guys forgot that every statement should end with semicolon in c check out your posts ! buddys :)

Comment: sizeof(char) is *per definition* == 1

Comment: Also, using str1 as destination buffer *and* as an input argument invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use sprintf; something like this:

```
char *str1 = malloc(256*sizeof(char));
char *str2 = "stack";
*str1 = '\0';
for (i=0;i<15;i++){
    snprintf(str1 + strlen(str1), 256 - strlen(str1), "%s", str2);
} 
printf("%s\n",str1);
```

Comment: snprintf is only C99 (not C89)

Answer (score 4):

According to the CERT Secure Coding Guidelines, you need to [use pointers to const when referring to string literals](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/STR05-C.+Use+pointers+to+const+when+referring+to+string+literals).

So, `char *str2 = "stack"` needs to be `const char *str2 = "stack";`.

This will make it immutable.

Additionally, you are using [deprecated/obsolete functions](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/MSC34-C.+Do+not+use+deprecated+or+obsolescent+functions). The secure function you should be using is `strcat_s`. For example,

***Compliant Example***

```
enum { BUFFERSIZE=256 };

void complain(const char *msg) {
  static const char prefix[] = "Error: ";
  static const char suffix[] = "\n";
  char buf[BUFFERSIZE];

  strcpy_s(buf, BUFFERSIZE, prefix);
  strcat_s(buf, BUFFERSIZE, msg);
  strcat_s(buf, BUFFERSIZE, suffix);
  fputs(buf, stderr);
}
```

Read here about [strcpy_s() and strcat_s()](https://buildsecurityin.us-cert.gov/bsi/articles/knowledge/coding/314-BSI.html).

Comment: @Tom: Ah another Floridian. Nice.

Comment: @Tom: Ha - no but that would be funny. We should probably head to chat if we are to discuss this further though :)

Comment: Note that `strcpy_s` and `strcat_s` are MS-specific extensions and not universally supported.  WG14 is working towards standardizing these (and other) functions, but AFAIK they have not been officially adopted and are not yet part of the language standard.  So don't rely on them being available everywhere.

Comment: @John: Good point. On *nix platforms, you should use strlcpy (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strlcpy)

Answer (score 0):

The standard C function for string concatenation is `char * strncat ( char * destination, char * source, size_t num );`.

Comment: But i want to use sprintf, not strcat.

Comment: `strncat()`, or you're just inviting a buffer overflow.

Comment: So? It's not the documented purpose of sprintf.

Comment: @thetux, then use `strnprintf`

Comment: But it can concatenate strings, right? For overflow problems there is also snprintf.

Answer (score -1):

Use [`strncat`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncat):

```
char *str1 = malloc(256*sizeof(char));
str1[0] = '\0';
char *str2 = "stack"
for (i=0;i<15;i++){
     strncat(str1, str2, 256 - 1 - strlen(str2));
} 
printf("%s\n",str1);
```

Comment: -1: str1 is uninitialized, you can't strncat to an uninitialized string. use calloc or set str1[0]=0

Comment: Good point. I saw that in the question code, but forgot to correct it in mine. Edited.